# Best way to migrate data from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access-2007

**The problem**

Ok, sorry that my question is somewhat abstract and subjective, but will try to make it as specific as possible. So, the situation I am in is simple - I am remaking a very old MS Access application on a new website using ASP.NET MVC. As currently the MVC site is using SQL Server 2008 (for many well known reasons) I need to find a way to migrate the tables AND the data, because the information in the old database will be used in the new application.

Alright, so far so good, however there are a few problems. The old application is written in a different language, meaning that I want to translate table names, field names, and all other names that are there to English. Furthermore, I will be making some changes on the models themselves (change the type of some fields, add additional fields to some tables, remove old unnecessary ones and more). So technically I'll be 'having my way' with everything.

**Researched solutions**

With those things in mind I researched for the ways to migrate data from Access database to a SQL Server. Of course, there is a lot of information on the matter, in Stack Overflow alone there are more than a few questions and solutions. So why am I struggling to find the answer ? Well I found a few solutions that will be sufficient to some extend (actually will definitely solve my problems) but I am writing to ask if someone experienced has a better perspective on it than I do. Alright, the solutions and why I am still looking for advice: /I'll be listing just a couple of the most common and popular ones that I found, many of the others share the same capabilities and/or results /

1. Upsize Wizzard (Access) - this is a tool devised specifically for migrating tables and data from Access. It is my most favourite one for the moment as I find it kind of straightforward to work with and it provides good overall results. I was able to migrate the tables to SQL Server (along with the data of course) which more or less is what I am intending to do. It is fast, it seems like it allows you to migrate indexes, primary keys and even to my knowledge foreign keys (table relationships). The downsides of this tool, however, include that it ignores your queries (which I don't really need honestly) and it doesn't provide a way to change the model, names or types of the properties of the table you migrate - which is the thing I kind of prefer, because I will have to make more than a few changes, adding, renaming, deleting, etc. And then continue with the development process (of the application) which will lead to a few additional minor changes. And finally I would need to apply all changes (migration + all changes) on the production server, which overall is prone to mistakes as I will be doing it by hand (and there are more than a few tables).
2. SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) - ok, this is a separate tool (not included in Access) with again the same idea - to migrate data from Access to ... possibly everywhere, haven't researched that. Overall it offers more functionality and customizing from the Upsize Wizard, but of course it does it in a more complicated way. I haven't put enough effort to make a migration with this tool yet, as it involves a lot of installations and additional work, but according to my research it provides almost all (if not all) of the functionality I require. The downside however comes with the naming. As I mentioned it allows you to apply changes on the tables, schema, fields, indexes, keys and probably everything, but the articles advice that I change the names in Access first, as it will be easier and the migration process will run more smoothly. I am not allowed to make changes on the original Access database, as it will remain functional until the publish of the 'renewed' project, and the data inside it is being used, so a mere copy of the file is a solution I am not particularly fond of, because I might loose new records. Also I cant predict the changes I would want to make in the development process (as I said I believe I would want/need to apply some additional changes later on when I find 'weaknesses' in my data design in the development process) so I find it to be a little half baked solution.

**Conclusion**

The options presented, the way I see them, are two:

- Use the Upsize Wizard to migrate the access tables, then write a script that applies the changes I want to make. Then in the development process add any additional changes to the script. When ready to publish on the production server, reapply the migration with the wizard, run the changes script and pray everything is fine.
- Get more involved with the SSMA tool and try producing an updated version of the tables with the migration process. (See how efficient the renaming is and decide whether to use copied file to rename and then find a way to migrate only new records or do it all in the SSMA). Then again write a script for the changes that occur in the development process and re-do and apply it all on the production server when ready and then pray everything is fine.
- Option I have not yet seen, apply it and then pray everything is fine.

I have researched the matter for a couple of days now, and found a few more solutions that I do not believe are better by the mentioned. However I include the possibility of missing the 'big red X on the map', a practical and easy solution which seems like it was designed specifically for me (though I doubt that a little). Anyway, reducing all the madness that I have written so far to a few simple questions will look like:

- Is anyone aware if my conclusions are correct? I am leaning towards option one as it is easier to accomplish.
- Has anyone experienced/found a better way to do that, or just found some 'logic-leaps' in my writings as I am overthinking the entire thing a little and may be doing some obvious miscalculation.

Very sorry for asking a trivial question and one that includes decision making that may involve deeper understanding of my project and situation, yet I am working with rather sensitive data and would appreciate feedback, even if only to improve my confidence into the chosen approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one other tool/method you might want to consider that seems to cater to your specific needs more. This would be to use the data import/export tool that ships with sqlserver to do a complete copy of all data into a temporary location within sql server and then write custom queries to reorganize the names and other changes you want to make. Is a bit more work but you could use the end product as a seed method for your migrations ;) (if you are doing code first anyway)

Comment: I did a couple of tests with the tool and it works very well. I imported my data and was exposed to an api that can edit practically anything of the model you are entering. Thanks, will save me some writing, even though I would script most of my changes so I wont have to enter all in the wizzard (could make naming mistakes, forget something and etc.) Thanks for the suggestion, it looks like I missed exactly the best fitting tool :)